# Sort Posts By Category?

Tags: loop, filters, sort

Googled this for hours, cannot find a solution.

On my [theme](http://www.elevancement.com/themes/browse/) you have a `Browse` page which pulls all the videos from the Custom Post Type I am working with. If a user makes 30 categories then id like for users to be able to sort the videos using the Category buttons listed at the top. If they click on `Horror` id like to loop to show all `Horror` Videos.

How can I sort my videos using Categories within this loop?

**BROWSE PAGE**

My Category ul li a

```
<ul class="sort-by-category">
    <?
      $args = array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'parent' => 0
      );
      $categories = get_categories( $args );
      foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo '<li><a class="browse-categories" href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
      }
    ?>
  </ul>
<? 
    // Our variables
    $numPosts = (isset($_GET['numPosts'])) ? $_GET['numPosts'] : 0;
    $page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;

    query_posts(array(
          'posts_per_page' => $numPosts,
          'paged'          => $page,
          'post_type'      => 'theme_video'
    ));

    // our loop
    if (have_posts()) {
          while (have_posts()){
                the_post();
                get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'browse' );
          }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
  ?>
```

I'm a bit lost on how to proceed. Nothing I tried seems to sort the loop, and the methods ive used have been outdated by 1-2 years...

Site works well for my first theme, but I do not know how to get this loop to sort by the category you select. Any tips or pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: I strongly recommend against using `query_posts`, use `WP_Query` instead

Comment: Understood. Would I simple replace `query_posts` with `WP_Query` ?

Comment: You should take a look at the "You don't know query" slides by Andrew Nacin http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks ill check it out now. :) still a bit new to query, loop, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `orderby` parameter in your query but you are missing the companion `order`.  This gives ascending/descending rule to the sortation.

WordPress [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) reference

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble understanding the question, but I'm assuming the code snippet you posted containing `query_posts` is in a category, archive or index template which is called when you follow on of the links generated by `get_category_link ()`. If so, the `query_posts` function is overriding the default loop, but you're not including the category to filter by so it's grabbing all posts in that post type.

```
// Our variables
$numPosts = (isset($_GET['numPosts'])) ? $_GET['numPosts'] : 0;
$page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;

// build query
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => $numPosts,
  'paged'          => $page,
  'post_type'      => 'theme_video'
);

// get category ID
$cat_id = get_query_var( 'cat' );

// add category to query if an id is found
if ( $cat_id != '' ) {
  $cat = get_category ( $cat_id );
  $args['category'] = $cat->slug;
}

// go!
query_posts( $args );
```

On another not I'd suggest looking into using the `pre_get_posts` hook as opposed to the `query_posts` function.

Comment: I appreciate your post, and I think we are close. On my [theme](http://www.elevancement.com/themes/browse/) you have a `Browse` page which pulls all the videos from the Custom Post Type I am working with. If a user makes 30 categories id like for users to be able to sort the videos using the Category buttons listed at the top. If they click on `Horror` id like to loop to show all `Horror` Videos. Can this code achieve that, and how can I link my Category Links to make the loop transition this way? See OP.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Answer has been found and I am posting it for anyone else who has this issue. If you have better ways of accomplishing this then please post below for the benefit of others.

Place this code in your **category.php.** It will automatically grab the category from the URL and pass it to the `cat => $category_id` and update the loop accordingly.

```
<ul class="sort-by-category">
<?
  $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'parent' => 0
  );
  $categories = get_categories( $args );
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<li><a class="browse-categories" href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a></li>';
  }
?>
</ul>

<?
    // Our variables
    $page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;

    // grab slug from url
    $category_id = get_query_var('cat');

    // define args
            $args = array( 
                        'posts_per_page' => '36',
          'paged'          =>  $page,
          'post_type'      => 'theme_video',
          'cat'            =>  $category_id
     );

            // place args in query
            $category_posts = new WP_Query($args);

            // our loop
            if($category_posts->have_posts()) { 
            while($category_posts->have_posts()) { 
                    $category_posts->the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'browse' );
            }
    } 
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```